# INSERT 2000 records into SQL Database all at a time from C# .NET code

Tags: sql-server

We need to INSERT 2000 records into SQL DB from C# .Net code.
For this is there any way to INSERT all 2000 records at a time instead of executing the INSERT query for each record.
Also how would be the performance impact of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

you can do it quickly using SqlBulkCopy:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=323

We use this to import a dataset of about 100,000 records into a SQL table in a few seconds, where 100,000 insert statements took 15 minutes.

Comment: That's the way to go, for sure!

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is seriously one of the must underrated adapters in the SqlClient namespace - it's lightning fast at importing large amounts of data.

Comment: just be careful if you have a primary key constraint, you may have to add IGNORE_DUP_KEY on sql table

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could build a query that has multiple inserts in it:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) values (@val1,@val2);" +
             "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) values (@val3,@val4);"
```

But dealing with the parameters for the command would get a bit tricky.

You can also use [DataAdapters and DataTables to do batch inserts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx).  That would probably be the best option, although the usage is a bit strange (not nearly as nice as Java's `addBatch() / executeBatch()` for example).

Performance wise, you'll almost certainly get a nice performance boost by doing this, although you might need to play around with the batch size a bit to figure out what works best

Comment: I don't think this will help much, especially when compared to the performance of SqlBulkCopy....

Comment: @marc_s - I've found the performance to be pretty good, but I've never tried SqlBulkCopy either.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way you can do it in  batch from C# code. 2000 rows will be quick to insert though.

One option may be available to you if you have the 2000 records in a flat file, you could copy it to the SQL server and create SP to BULK INSERT the file into a table. Then call the SP from your C# code. I would not bother unless you see having more rows than that and if you have huge target table.

Comment: This is **not true**. .NET includes the very powerful **SQLBulkCopy** class which is **THE** fastest way of inserting data into a SQL Database.